# Creating an oval in html with centered text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-shapes

I have a number of ovals I need to put into a WordPress page so it looks like;

```
oval - paragraph
paragraph - oval
oval - paragraph
paragraph - oval
oval - paragraph
```

I have no problems creating the oval, however I need to style it so no matter what heading text I put into each oval - it stays uniform.

I have put hard values in using padding-top however for 1 line headers this is no longer going to be centered.

How can I approach this better?

```css
div {
  background-color: #1468a8;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence;
    <br/>Affirming Values
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gcampton/QGtzW/1025/

Comment: what do you mean by "stays uniform"?

Comment: I mean once you change text to three lines, it no longer is centered. The table property works best as it doesn't require any hard values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following css to make div and text center. Use `display: table;` and `table-cell` will solved your issue.

```
div {
    background-color: #1468a8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    display: table;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
p {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/1026/)

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the height of the `div` and use top/bottom padding to center the text verticaly :

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcampton/QGtzW/1025/)

```css
div {
  background-color: #1468a8;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  padding: 14% 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence;
    <br />Affirming Values</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence;</p>
</div>
```

*NOTE: you also forgot the closing tag for the `<p>` element*

Answer (score 2):

See the fiddle, I have added two more oval in HTML, which contains different content, all three inherits same class still vertical and middle alignment is perfect for all three. here is fiddle for the same 
https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/rv7mnw7s/

Below is my code

The HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence; Affirming Values</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence; Affirming Values & lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Accepting Divergence</p>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
div {
  background-color: #1468a8;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```